# Prove that a monotone sequence of real numbers is convergent if and only if it is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

To prove for a decreasing sequence.  I'm getting difficulties with the second part

1. First I assumed it is convergent and and prove that it is bounded.
2. Assume bounded and prove convergent
   I have used completeness property $\ X_n$ $\geq M$ for all $n \in N $ where M is the infimum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For any $\epsilon > 0$, $M+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound for the sequence. Hence there exists $X_n$ such that
$$
M+\epsilon > X_n \geq M
$$